# How to get fields and properties accessed by a method of same class?

Tags: roslyn

I tried to look through the syntax tree, but the information is not sufficient enough, so I created a compilation and got the semantic model of the syntax tree. Now I can get properties and fields declarations using `OfType<T>` extension method where `T` is `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` or `FieldDeclarationSyntax`.

Inside a method.`Body.Statements` I thought I could look for symbols representing the ones I got from `OfType<T>`. But I am having a hard time figuring that part out. The syntax tree just identifies the symbol as "IdentifierName", which is not much helpful..

If this is not the correct way of looking at it, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol()` on the `PropertyDeclartionSyntax` or the one of the `VariableDeclaratorSyntax` inside the `FieldDefinitionSyntax`.  Then use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo()` on the identifiers and see if they match.  (Note that you should use `ISymbol.Equals` as you might not get reference equal results.

Comment: This did help. Although there's one little caveat to recognizing `Field`s. Instead of blindly passing `FieldDeclarationSyntax` to `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol()` we have to pass in `FieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Variable` from each `Variables`. Reason is, field declaration can be used to declare multiple fields as opposed to properties, which can only declare one symbol.